# How to Convert MS PowerPoint 2003/2007 into HTML using APACHE POI or Else?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, apache-poi

I need to convert PowerPoint 2003/2007(ppt/pptx) to HTML. But I have not found any code how to do this. So, how to Convert MS PowerPoint 2003/2007(ppt/pptx) into HTML using APACHE POI or Else? I have found Apache POI. But don't know what code can do the trick

Comment: Do you just need the text out, with perhaps a bit of formatting, or do you need to render something very close to the original file (including links etc)?

Comment: @Gagravarr, Yes I need the text. So that I can allow user to edit this?

Comment: You want them to be able to edit the text as HTML, then have that magically update the ppt file? Or just edit it and have it stay in html?

Comment: I need the functionality like Google Doc's PowerPoint.

Comment: Why not just use the Google Docs API then?

Comment: @Gagravarr, I need to save the files in my documents locally? Is it possible with google.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will not find a complete example, but if you follow the tutorial to read a file and how to extract data from each slide (http://poi.apache.org/slideshow/quick-guide.html) you will be able to perform what you want.

Comment: Thanks I will check that. It will be helpful, if you provide a simple example

Answer (score 1):

i would say 'or else', but depends on what do you exactly need. if your ppt has very strict and known layout and you need html to be clickable, have links etc, you can try to do it. we chose different approach. we connected to running instance of power point using COM library and we just executed powerpoint commands directly. however i don't see any 'save as html' so seems like choosing this way you will have to save ppt as a picture and then create html with it. it's a big pain in the ass to develop it but once done you can have very complex presentations without any additional work

Comment: sure. http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/ and wiki: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/jacob-project/index.php?title=Main_Page

Answer (score 1):

Apache POI can be used to read powerpoint (ppt/pptx) and extract data.
You may find [this](http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/ReadPowerPoint) article important on doing that. If you want .pptx use use org.apache.poi.xslf.XSLFSlideShow instead of HSLSFSlideShow, and then use the classes in org.apache.poi.xslf.* instead of the ones in org.apache.poi.hssf.*

Comment: any simple example will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this needs to be a programmatic solution.

You could do this by writing your own Servlet that looks at the files contents and reproduces them using the various classes the POI Powerpoint library has to offer.

You could change each slide to an [image](http://poi.apache.org/slideshow/xslf-cookbook.html#PPTX2PNG) and then display it in an html img tag.

You could also try working with a raw xml dump. You could get this and then turn it into an html document using an xslt file. I think this would only work with newer files(.pptx) using xslf.

note: The functionality you will need is likely to be limited depending on which file you are transforming http://poi.apache.org/slideshow/index.html. The older files must use hslf whilst the newer OOXML based files can use xlsf. "There is currently no common interface".

Comment: Thanks but I need the html not image.